# How to append to the end of a C Array

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, pointers

I've been programming for a while in objective-c, but I've unfortunately never delved very deeply into C and memory pointers, although I do have a rudimentary understanding of them. I'm working with an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D structures, and I'm trying to figure out how to append to the array. First of all, I get the

```
NSString *aString; //a bunch of coordinates
CLLocationCoordinate2d *coordinates;
int length;

doSomethingCool(aString, &coordinates, &length);
```

after I do something cool, I want to preserve it in a class variable. If I simply do something like

```
points = newPoints
```

*points* contains the appropriate contents. However, if I try to do something like this:

```
points = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * length);
points[0] = *newPoints;
```

*points* ends up with contents different from *newPoints*.

Ultimately my goal is to be able to append to *points* based on *length*, but I'm not going to be able to do that if I can't get the above code to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code simply copies the first value of `newPoints` into the first value of `points` (`*newPoints` is equivalent to `newPoints[0]`).

One situation is to make a new array, copy all values, switch the arrays, and free() the old one. For example:

```
int* newvals = malloc(sizeof(int) * newcount);
memcpy(newvals, vals, sizeof(int) * oldcount);
free(vals);
vals = newvals;
```

You can also use `realloc` - its behavior is similar to the above (though it can fail!), but at times may be more efficient.

Note that you simply can't change the underlying pointer's size in a safe and portable fashion. You will need to update your instance ("class") variable with the new pointer.

Comment: That makes so much sense about how C treats memory! So, according to your example, if I wanted to append data to newvals, would something like "memcpy(newvals[oldcount + 1], vals, sizeof(int) * oldcount)" work?

Comment: For performance, maintainability and readability of code I suggest the use of realloc as noted by the OP. One classic pitfall with realloc btw is that you : malloc(100*sizeof(int)) want to increase to 200 and do realloc(100*sizeof(int)) but realloc does not sum up to do this you need realloc(200*sizeof(int)). As a sidenode malloc can also fail.

Comment: @myself: close, it should be "memcpy(&tempvals[oldcount], vals, sizeof(int) * oldcount); free(newvals); newvals = tempvals;", keeping in mind that the first value of an array is 0; hence "&tempvals[oldcount]" instead of "&tempvals[oldcount + 1]"

Comment: Thanks for the tip Eduard; once I figured out what the syntax should be using memcpy, realloc made things much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to copy all of the array into a temporary array, resize the original, and then copy them back.  However, managing this could get hairy.  You'd be better off using an std::vector and just appending it.

EDIT:  I just realized you're using C, not C++.  Disregard the second half of this.

Comment: `NSMutableArray` in this case, lets not bring C++ into it.

Comment: I figured the question was best answered relying only on what is available in C; hence why I didn't tag it as Objective-C (though someone else did). Was I wrong?